# TypeScript - extract nested property from all properties in object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given an object that has several properties. Each property (`bla, foo, third`) has 2 sub-properties: `initialValue` and `actions`. The `actions` sub-property has different value each time, like that:

```
const myContainer = {
    bla: {
        initialValue: 1,
        actions: { 
            clear: () => {},
            increase: () => {}
        }
    },
    foo: {
        initialValue: 'FOO',
        actions: {
            foo: () => {}
        }
    },
    third: {
        initialValue: 133,
        actions: {
            doNothing: () => {}
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to get a type with only the `actions` sub-property but **typed**, which looks like that:

```
type MyActions = {
    bla: {
        clear: () => {},
        increase: () => {}
    },
    foo: {
        foo: () => {}
    },
    third: {
        doNothing: () => {}        
    }
};
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty simple mapped type, just access the `['actions']` in the value section.

```
type MyContainer = typeof myContainer;
type MyActions = {
    [T in keyof MyContainer]: MyContainer[T]['actions']
};
```

Comment: What is the best way to extract these values, not just type?

Comment: `const actions = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myContainer).map(([key, val]) => [key, val.actions]))`?